# jQuery hide with attributesStartsWith not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that populates that hides and shows divs based on whether or not it contains a portion of an Id, then shows the div that contains the full, unique Id passed to the function.  The function is as follows:

```
function showPlot(plotId) {
  // Hide all plots by switching them to a class
  $('div[id^="plot_"').hide(); //<--Won't hide the divs matching that portion of the Id
  // Show the selected plot by changing it's class
  $('#' + plotId).show('fast');
}
```

The problem is the .hide() function won't hide the specified divs as expected.  I might not have the syntax right, but I'm pretty sure it's correct according to the API.  Is there something else I'm missing?  Help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the function being called correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the closing `]`.

```
$('div[id^="plot_"]')
             //   ^---------was missing
```

Comment: Will it work with those quotes around `plot_`? I think jQuery will look for an element with `id=""plot_""` where the inner quotes are part of the actual id if that makes sense. Maybe not

Comment: @Connor: No, jQuery will not look for that ID. In fact quotes are mandatory: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: @Connor: Yes it will work like that. The quotation marks are actually mandatory now for the value of the various *attribute selectors*.

Comment: @patrick dw They are? Woah okay I'll be right back got some code to change.

Comment: @Connor: I think it still works without them, but better be on the safe side ;)

Comment: @Connor: Yeah, they were always supported, but you used to be able to exclude them. Not too long ago, they quietly changed the docs to make them mandatory. :o)

Comment: @patrick dw Are you sure they are actually mandatory? I just updated to latest jQuery a couple days ago and nothing broke

Comment: "Attribute values in selector expressions must be surrounded by quotation marks." Seems so, but my `$('[data-control=prev]')` etc's have not broken yet. I'll change them now ^^

Comment: @Connor: The docs state that they're mandatory. It may work in some (or even all) supported browsers to exclude them, but then you're using the API in an unsupported manner, so it could break in the future.

Comment: I just learned this the other day - the docs say they are mandatory, but quotes are required only if your string contains characters of significance to a regex. Here's a quick demo for demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/Ender/Fy8ue/

Comment: Works both ways in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/waitinforatrain/gyLbS/

Comment: Is this still the case? According to the link @Felix Kling posted above "value An attribute value. Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string."

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$('div[id^="plot_"').hide();
```

to

```
$('div[id^="plot_"]').hide(); // you were missing the last ]
```